# Bug on Microsoft launcher

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

Minecraft Java launcher falsely states that internet is not available but it is and works with every other application. Brand new computer with nothing installed (Christmas Present). The error seems to be around since Sept 2021 but why isn't it fixed. Is there a place to get an updated launcher?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't notice the bit at the bottom: "Is there a place to get an updated launcher?", which is why I didn't answer sooner.

If updates are failing, you can download the latest Minecraft launcher from [here](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download). You may need to log in to your account.